# how to extract text from link (href) when its withing li.h3

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to extract text from  link (href) when its withing li.h3 
follwoing is my code:

```
<div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="263050872757">
        <div class="lvpicinner full-width picW">

<div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="urgency"></div>
    <a class="img imgWr2" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/LEGO-31313-Mindstorms-EV3-Robot-Technic-NEW-SEALED-/263050872757?epid=140182845&amp;hash=item3d3f0dc7b5:g:4EIAAOSwLsBZS6bF">
                 <img class="img" alt="LEGO 31313 Mindstorms EV3 - Robot Technic ***NEW &amp; SEALED***" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/4EIAAOSwLsBZS6bF/s-l225.jpg">
            </a>
        </div></div>
<h3 class="lvtitle"><a title="Click this link to access LEGO 31313 Mindstorms EV3 - Robot Technic ***NEW &amp; SEALED***" class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/LEGO-31313-Mindstorms-EV3-Robot-Technic-NEW-SEALED-/263050872757?epid=140182845&amp;hash=item3d3f0dc7b5:g:4EIAAOSwLsBZS6bF">LEGO 31313 Mindstorms EV3 - Robot Technic ***NEW &amp; SEALED***</a>
    </h3>
```

Comment: _"follwoing is my code"_ – please show your Ruby code as well. Besides, how is your question related to RSpec?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your question? What are you trying to accomplish, do you have that page and want to check the content in your Rspec test? Or do you simply need to parse that page and get the input?

Comment: First let me share i am new to learning Ruby/Watir, please bare with me. What i am trying to achive is get the Text value to the hyperlink link tag a so that i can verify that i got the relevent result for my search string, but i am unable to parse where i can reach the text for <h3 class="lvtitle">.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. But if you are looking to grab the href in `<a>` tags, within the `<h3>` tags and parse it, you could do something like this. Hope that helps.

```
 document.querySelector('.lvtitle .vip').href.split("/")
```

This would be the results of the above query:

```
 ["http:", "", "www.ebay.com", "itm", "LEGO-31313-Mindstorms-EV3-Robot-
 Technic-NEW-SEALED-", "263050872757?
 epid=140182845&hash=item3d3f0dc7b5:g:4EIAAOSwLsBZS6bF"]
```